# How can I convert a char array containing the user ID to uid_t?

Tags: c, linux, c11

I have a character array containing my user ID. I need to get a uid_t object so I can look up the username using getpwuid(3).

My command is `./foo 1000` (a user with the name 'bar' and the ID 1000 exists on the system). Here's my code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct passwd *user = getpwuid((int) argv[1]);

    printf("%s\n", user->pw_name);
}
```

The problem with this is, getpwuid(3) only accepts uid_t, and the (int) casting is not working.

I am well aware that I could use getpwnam() and get it from a string, but I can't figure out how to convert my char array to a uid_t so getpwuid(3) accepts it.

Comment: You're looking for `atoi(3)`.

Comment: Casting here is really wrong, so please, take this as a moment to learn what that casting actually does. C does conversion between only a handful of types when casting, this is the exception not the norm.